Facebook js sdk page access token
So i am building a backend project that interacts with Facebook graph api, i create two end points, one that bring me page info and one that brings me page post the thing is that i first i get the user access token then i get the page access token.
The problem show when  using react in the front-end if i call both this api i get this bug that you can't use user access token to get this kinda of data (pagr info and post) while my code specifically use the retrieved page access token
The problem keeps if i called the page info component and the posts components
const getPage_Info_Insights = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // FB.setAccessToken(userAccessToken); // Set the user access token

    const pageId = req.params.id; // Get the page ID from the route parameters

    // Define the fields to fetch extra page info
    const fields = [
      "id",
      "access_token",
      "about",
      "category",
      "name",
      "cover",
      "fan_count",
      "engagement",
      "followers_count",
    ];
    console.log("fetching");

    // Fetch the page info including the page access token
    // const pageInfo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //   FB.api(`/${pageId}`, { fields: fields.join(",") }, (response) => {
    //     if (!response || response.error) {
    //       reject(
    //         new Error(
    //           response.error
    //             ? response.error.message
    //             : "Failed to fetch page info"
    //         )
    //       );
    //     } else {
    //       resolve(response);
    //     }
    //   });
    // });

    // if (!pageInfo || !pageInfo.access_token) {
    //   return res.status(400).json({
    //     success: false,
    //     message: "Unable to retrieve page access token or page info",
    //   });
    // }

    // Use the page-specific access token for fetching insights
    // FB.setAccessToken(pageInfo.access_token);
    let pageInfo = await func.getPageAccessToken(pageId, fields);
    // console.log(pageInfo);

    if (pageInfo.access_token) {
      let FB = func.getMetaObject(pageInfo.access_token);
      // console.log(FB);
      const { metrics, since, until } = req.query;
      const metricsToFetch = metrics ? metrics.split(",") : metrics_all; // Assume metrics_all is defined elsewhere

      // Prepare the API request for metrics
      const insightsPromises = metricsToFetch.map((metric) => {
        const params = {
          metric,
          period: "day",
        };

        if (since) params.since = since;
        if (until) params.until = until;

        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          FB.api(`/${pageId}/insights`, params, function (response) {
            if (response && !response.error) {
              resolve({ metric, data: response.data });
            } else {
              resolve({
                metric,
                error: response.error
                  ? response.error.message
                  : "Error fetching insights",
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });

      // Wait for all metrics to be fetched
      const results = await Promise.all(insightsPromises);

      // Process results...
      const insightsData = {};
      const errors = [];

      results.forEach((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          errors.push({ metric: result.metric, message: result.error });
        } else {
          insightsData[result.metric] = result.data;
        }
      });

      // Send the aggregated page info and insights data back to the client
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        pageInfo: {
          id: pageInfo.id,
          about: pageInfo.about,
          category: pageInfo.category,
          name: pageInfo.name,
          access_token: pageInfo.access_token,
          cover: pageInfo.cover,
          fan_count: pageInfo.fan_count,
          engagement: pageInfo.engagement,
          followers_count: pageInfo.followers_count,
        },
        insights: insightsData,
        errors,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching page insights and info:", error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Failed to fetch page insights or info",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
};

